# I don't understand formula meaning of computer vision Paper

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, mathematical-foundations, mathematical-analysis, digital-image-processing

I am master degree student at Computer Science Department.
I started master degree at this year.
Now I'm reading two papers about computer vision.
Actually before time I didn't have experience about computer vision. so I am not familiar with the concepts used in this field.

OK. I want start question.
I am reading these paper. 
1) Template Matching using Fast Normalized Cross Correlation 
by "Kai Briechle and Uwe D. Hanebeck
2) Fast Template Matching
by J.P. Lewis

Question 1. In the above  "2) paper" we can see formula like bottom, f(x,y) is source Image, t(x,y) is 
template Image. 
[image]

**I wonder why two red box term to be constant and remove**. I thank that just mathematically.
Who can explain to me? by using some picture or easily. I don't understand by image processing field.

Question 2. In the above "1) paper" I don't understand red box term (average value) to be that.
because, In usually We can calculate average value like this (value1 + value2 / 2)

[image]

Comment: It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: What does this mean? "I wonder why two red box term to be constant and remove"

Comment: Ah . My mean is "Why red box term to be constant, and to be removed"